# $|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(a_k x)}{k^2}|\leq |\tan x|$, prove $a_k=o(k^2),\;k\to\infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{a_k\}$ is a positive sequence, and
$$
|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(a_k x)}{k^2}|\leq |\tan x|,\quad\text{$x\in(-1,\,1).$}
$$
Prove that $a_k=o(k^2),\;k\to\infty$.

I could not even how to start it.